# GPX track not show in Leaflet map

Tags: leaflet, geojson, html, gpx

I  would like to display a map featuring both a marker and a track, the latter loaded from a GPX file on my local machine. I have been trying to use the [leaflet-gpx](https://github.com/mpetazzoni/leaflet-gpx) plugin but since I am totally new to Leaflet, geodata, JavaScript...

I can't figure out why the track does not appear on the map, whereas the marker does. The GPX file is located in the same directory as my HTML file, and the GPX seems to be valid as the track is displayed when I upload it to an online GPX viewer.

Here is my code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.3.1/leaflet.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/1.3.1/leaflet.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet-gpx/1.4.0/gpx.min.js"></script>

    <div id="mapid" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>
    <script>
    var map = L.map('mapid').setView([50.343, 8.677], 13);
      L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
         maxZoom: 18,
         attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +
            '<a href="https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/2.0/">CC-BY-SA</a>, ' +
            'Imagery © <a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>',
         tileSize: 512,
         zoomOffset: -1
      }).addTo(map);

    var marker = L.marker([50.343, 8.677]).addTo(map);
    var gpx = 'tracks.gpx'; // URL to your GPX file or the GPX itself
    new L.GPX(gpx, {async: true}).on('loaded', function(e) {
      map.fitBounds(e.target.getBounds());
    }).addTo(map);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The above uses the example code found on the leaflet-gpx github site, which is why it does not use the latest version of leaflet. I would like to use the latest version in future, but first I'd like to get this simple example working (I've also tried converting the data to GeoJSON format and displaying that instead, but again no luck, so I guess I'm doing something fundamentally wrong).

**UPDATE: excerpt from GPX file added**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<gpx xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" creator="Best-Mountain-Artists" version="1.1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd">

  <metadata>
    <link href="http://best-mountain-artists.de">
      <text>Best-Mountain-Artists</text>
    </link>
    <time>2017-11-24T09:00:27Z</time>
    <bounds maxlat="50.935044921934605" maxlon="8.247442189604044" minlat="50.89056090451777" minlon="8.172424659132958"/>
  </metadata>   <trk>
        <name>Wildkatzen-Walderlebnis Winterstein </name>
        <trkseg>
            <trkpt lat="50.341790" lon="8.673659">
                <ele>337.19223</ele>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.340613" lon="8.674818">
                <ele>346.23657</ele>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.340092" lon="8.674088">
                <ele>357.13358</ele>
            </trkpt>
            <trkpt lat="50.340448" lon="8.667651">
                <ele>361.92911</ele>
            </trkpt>
...
            <trkpt lat="50.341755" lon="8.673716">
                <ele>337.40000</ele>
            </trkpt>
        </trkseg>
    </trk>
</gpx>
```

Comment: You need to reproject your track to epsg:3857

Comment: @IanTurton That's not true. If you look at the example http://mpetazzoni.github.io/leaflet-gpx/, you'll see that GPX coordinates are standard lat, long.

Comment: @canavanin Can you post a part of your `tracks.gpx` file?

Comment: @TomazicM  Done :)

Comment: @TomazicM but the map is in epsg:3857 so the points will need reprojecting or they will show up on Null Island

Comment: @IanTurton And why then http://mpetazzoni.github.io/leaflet-gpx/ works OK?

Comment: I have no idea but this is the most common cause of this issue with leaflet maps

Comment: @IanTurton All parameters to Leaflet functions/methods are standard lat,lng format (see for example https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.6.0.html#polygon) regardless of map projection. This plugin uses Leaflet functions/methods in constructing track, that's why it's OK. In OpenLayers that would not be the case.

Comment: That code [works for me](https://plnkr.co/edit/QPKt3wo7P91pU0l6). Please ensure that your example is [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Do you get any errors in the debugger console?

Comment: @IvanSanchez When I click on the "works for me" link you've provided all I get is a completely blank page. And in my question I've posted the exact code I'm using, nothing more and nothing less. For me this code does not produce the desired output,  I don't know what I could do to make it fail reproducibly on another machine.

Comment: @TomazicM No errors, but if I select "pause on caught exceptions" there is the following message for leaflet.js: "TypeError: document.namespaces is undefined"

Comment: Which OS and browser are you using (because it also works for me)?

Comment: @TomazicM I'm using Firefox 74.0.1 (32-bit) on Ubuntu 16.04. I've also tried the Chromium browser but the result is the same: map and marker, but no track :(

Comment: @IvanSanchez Thanks to TomayicM's comment I've tried your Plunker-link in Chromium, there I do see a result, not just a blank page as in Firefox.

Comment: I've also tried in in Google Chrome on Windows 10, same result. All I do is open the HTML file in the browser, is there anything else I should be doing?

Comment: Is your app html file local file or it sits on server?

Comment: @TomazicM It's just an HTML file on my local machine, no server involved as yet.

Comment: This means you GPX is not displayed for security reasons. It's being read by AJAX call (`window.XMLHttpRequest()`), which is not allowed for local files.

Comment: @TomazicM Ah, thanks very much!